# Clear Request.IsAuthenticated value after SignOut() without RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, logout

I am writing an account management controller and have to process deleting of own user's account separately:

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Delete(string userName, string confirmButton)
{
    MembershipService.DeleteUser(userName);

    if (User.Identity.Name.Equals(userName,
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        FormsAuth.SignOut();

        return View("DeleteSelf");
    }
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But partial view LogOnUserControl.ascx still shows just logged out user name while displaying DeleteSelf view because Request.IsAuthenticated and Page.User.Identity values are still set after FormsAuth.SignOut().

Adding a new action ShowDeleteSelfMessage could solve the problem but I don't like this solution:

```
    ...
    {
        FormsAuth.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("ShowDeleteSelfMessage");
    }
    ...

public ActionResult ShowDeleteSelfMessage()
{
    return View("DeleteSelf");
}
```

Any other ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your LogOnUserControl.ascx to deal with ViewData["UserDeleted"]:

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Delete(string userName, string confirmButton)
{
    MembershipService.DeleteUser(userName);

    if (User.Identity.Name.Equals(userName,
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        FormsAuth.SignOut();

        // ***
        ViewData["UserDeleted"] = true;
        // ***

        return View("DeleteSelf");
    }
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

LogOnUserControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !(ViewData["UserDeleted"] ?? false)) { %>
    Welcome <b><%= Html.Encode(Page.User.Identity.Name) %></b>!
    [ <%= Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") %> ]
<% } else { %> 
    [ <%= Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") %> ]
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Delete` action, instead of `return View("DeleteSelf")`, try this `return Redirect("DeleteSelf")`

Comment: I tried and learned what unfortunately this is equivalent to RedirectToAction("DeleteSelf")

Comment: Isn't that different from your OP, which is return View("DeleteSelf")?

Comment: Unfortunately the same. But I think now what adding separate action to show a view is common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have examined the source code of standard AccountController.cs file and found two methods

```
public ActionResult ChangePasswordSuccess()
{
    return View("ChangePasswordSuccess");
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult RestorePasswordSuccess()
{
    return View("RestorePasswordSuccess");
}
```

which only show corresponding views. So my

```
public ActionResult ShowDeleteSelfMessage()
{
    return View("DeleteSelf");
}
```

method will look good in such company. Though I should change the name for consistency.